# Rails: remember user input in devise registration form after error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Rails 3.2.16 and devise 3.2.2.

I've added a (hidden) field `account_level` to my devise registration form. This is populated by a query string in the URL depending on what plan the user chooses.

If the user has an error with the registration form, such as the password do not match or a required field isn't filled in, the registration page then reloads with the errors present. However, the `account_level` field is now blank and the url does not have the query string on it for me to pull the data from it.

How can I have rails "remember" what was in that field after a page reload if a error occurs?

Bonus sanity check question: Is there a better way to pass which plan the user has choose when registering?

----------- **Update** -----------
I used a combination of the answers from Shamsul and aelor. I ended up grabbing the value of the query string and saving it in a cookie using javascript. If the page then reloads from a validation error, and the query string on the URL is no longer there, I look for the cookie that was set and grab the value from there to populate the hidden field.
I want to keep as much on the front end, which is why I opted for the JS solution. I also felt like cookies are a more tried and tested vs local storage.

Answer (score 1):

use localStorage.

you can save your plan , when the user clicks it.

```
localStorage.setItem('plan','premium');
```

then you can check for the the item and fill up the hidden field.

```
if(localStorage.getItem('plan') != null){
   $('#hiddeninput').val(localStorage.getItem('plan'));
}
```

and you can delete that plan whenever you like by using

```
localStorage.removeItem('plan');
```

Comment: Thanks aelor for the answer. I used it in combination with another answer to get my final solution. Thank you for the help and taking time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

In registrations_controller.rb of devise

Store **account_level** field in a cookies as

```
def new
  if params[:account_level]
   cookies[:account_level] = params[:account_level]
  end
  #other code
end

def create
  if resource.save
    unless cookies[:account_level].nil?
     cookies.delete(:account_level)
     #do other coding
    end

  end
end
```

In this way **account_level** field will not blank after reloaing the page.

Comment: Thanks Shamsul for the answer. I used it in combination with another answer to get my final solution. Thank you for the help and taking time to answer.